# iPhone and iPad : Doing a "select * from something" query in a SQLite database

Tags: iphone, ipad, sqlite

i'm trying to use the SQLite data base in my iPad app, and here's my function to make a query:

```
- (void)executeQuery:(char*)query
{
    NSString *file = [self getWritableDBPath];
 NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
 BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:file]; 

 // If its not a local copy set it to the bundle copy
 if(!success) {
  //file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:DATABASE_TITLE ofType:@"db"];
  [self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];
 }

 dataArray = NULL;
 dataArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    sqlite3 *database = NULL;
    if (sqlite3_open([file UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_exec(database, query, loadTimesCallback, dataArray, NULL);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);

    [self logResults];
}
```

if I call `[self executeQuery:"select name from table1"];` everything is working fine. But if i call `[self executeQuery:"select * from cars"];` the app crashes telling me that the `NSMutableArray` dataArray is not the right kind of variable where to set the query results.

So, how can i do a "select * form table1" query, and store the results?

Thanks!

EDIT: Here's my loadTimesCallback method:

```
static int loadTimesCallback(void *context, int count, char **values, char **columns)
{
    NSMutableArray *times = (NSMutableArray *)context;
    for (int i=0; i < count; i++) {
        const char *nameCString = values[i];
        [times addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:nameCString]];
    }
    return SQLITE_OK;
}
```

Comment: it will be easier for your development to use fmdb, `https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb`, a nice SQLite wrapper in Objective C.

Comment: @Yuji: I posted my loadTimesCallback method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed [this tutorial](http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/) (look at fifth paragraph) and I solved all my problem

Comment: Thank you very much, this tutorial rulez! [Grazie mille Adriano, questo tutorial è davvero ben fatto!]

Comment: Yes, it's very clear. It helped me a lot [fa sempre piacere aiutare qualcuno con i tuoi stessi problemi]